# Restrict KMS key access per GKE workload

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-kms, workload-identity

I use GKE and I'm trying to have each workload have its own key in KMS.

I've been fiddling with IAM and Deny policies and conditions to somehow force a restriction so each workload can only **access their own key**. Deny conditionals won't work since [KMS is not listed as a supported resource](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/deny-permissions-support). Hence IAM would be the ideal solution but I can't seem to be able to find something I can use, e.g. something like "`request.user`" to match the GKE account.

This is the diagram:

```
┌─────────────────┐      ┌──────────────────────────────────┐      ┌───────┐
│      GKE        │      │   Workload Identity              │      │ KMS   │
├─────────────────┤      ├──────────────────────────────────┤      ├───────┤
│ myns1/myuser    │ ───► │ as myiamservice[myns1|myuser]    │ ───► │ myns1 │
├─────────────────┤      │                                  │      │       │
│ myns2/myuser    │ ───► │ as myiamservice[myns2|myuser]    │ ───► │ myns2 │
└─────────────────┘      └──────────────────────────────────┘      └───────┘
```

GKE has service accounts that are translated via Workload Identity into IAM identities. Then I need to somehow check where the request originated from (in GKE) since at this point all GKE entities share a single IAM service account. So if I could somehow check that the request maps to `myiamservice[myns1/myuser]`, then I can block or deny the request.

A fictional IAM policy example:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "role": "roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyDecrypter",
      "condition": {
        "title": "limit entities to their keys",
        "expression": "resource.name == request.user"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I wonder if this is possible. Mind that there might be 100s or 1000s of GKE entities, so just creating a IAM account per GKE entity is not realistic.

Answer (score -1):

**Using Terraform**

1. You shold create a service account for every user

> User 1 Service Account

```
resource "google_service_account" "myuser1" {
  project      = [project_id]
  account_id   = "myuser1"
  display_name = "myuser1"
}
```

> User 2 Service Account

```
resource "google_service_account" "myuser2" {
  project      = [project_id]
  account_id   = "myuser2
  display_name = "myuser2
}
```

2. Add worload identity for everyone.

> Workload Identity

```
resource "google_service_account_iam_binding" "ksa_user1" {
      service_account_id = google_service_account.myuser1.name
      role               = "roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser"
      members = [
        "serviceAccount:${[project_id]}.svc.id.goog[myns1|myuser]",
      ]
    }
...
```

3. You can give permissions individualy for every key for example with terraform:

> User 1 -> KMS key 1

```
resource "google_kms_crypto_key_iam_member" "iam_sa_user1_kms_encrypter_decrypter" {
  crypto_key_id = "myns1"
  role          = "roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter"
  member        = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.myuser1.email}"
}
```

> User 2 -> KMS key 2

```
resource "google_kms_crypto_key_iam_member" "iam_sa_user2_kms_encrypter_decrypter" {
      crypto_key_id = "myns2"
      role          = "roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter"
      member        = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.myuser2.email}"
    }
```

Comment: This feels like a ChatGPT copy pasta